# .innerHTML not updating HTML in Javascript

Tags: javascript

working on a rock paper scissors assignment where a global variable increments forward depending on whether the computer or the human wins. My functions work fine, but the scoreboard will not update when using .innerHTML. Any suggestions?

```
document.getElementById("humanScore").innerHTML = humanTotal;
document.getElementById("computerScore").innerHTML = compTotal;
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GvpaJ

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues you are having.

In your play function, you are not doing anything with `computerChoice` variable, and it should be a result of the function call to `compPlay()`. Presently it is `var computerChoice = compPlay`, which is actually assigning `computerChoice` to a function, not the result of it.

Secondly in the testing if statements, you are checking the value again `compPlay`, which is a function, I think it should be `computerChoice`

Thirdly. the return value from `compPlay` is an index, it should that index value from the `compOptions` array

updated code below

```
var humanTotal =0;                                          
var compTotal=0;                                    

document.getElementById("rock").onclick = setRock;
document.getElementById("paper").onclick = setPaper;
document.getElementById("scissors").onclick = setScissors;

function setRock(){
    play("rock")
}

function setPaper(){
    play("paper")
}

function setScissors(){
    play("scissors")
}    

function play(humanChoice) {    
    var computerChoice = compPlay(); //<-- Change Here

    //And all the following if statements to check the computer choice
    if (humanChoice == "rock"){
        if (computerChoice  =="rock"){
        } else if (computerChoice =="scissors"){
            humanTotal++; 
        } else if (computerChoice =="paper"){
            compTotal++;
        }
    }

    if (humanChoice == "paper"){
        if (computerChoice  =="paper"){
        } else if (computerChoice =="rock"){
            humanTotal++; 
        } else if (computerChoice =="scissors"){
        compTotal++;
        }
    }

    if (humanChoice == "scissors"){
        if (computerChoice  =="scissors"){
        } else if (computerChoice =="paper"){
            humanTotal++; 
        } else if (computerChoice =="rock"){
            compTotal++;
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("humanScore").innerHTML = humanTotal;
    document.getElementById("computerScore").innerHTML = compTotal;

}   


function compPlay (){
    var compOptions = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];    
    var randomChoice = Math.floor(Math.random()*compOptions.length);
    return compOptions[randomChoice]; //<-- Change Here

}
```

It has nothing to do with innerHTML, that is working fine, it was just that the score was always zero. The reason was because none of the if statements testing for "rock", "paper" or "scissors" ever resolved to true as the computerChoice never matched "rock","paper", or "scissors", so sorry but it was your functions.

Answer (score 1):

Your functions does not work fine. The `innerHTML`-part works like it should (proof: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qlIsG).

The problem is that you've made some error in your game logic that causes the scoreboard to end up 0-0 every time.

Good luck on your assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You have several mistakes, its not a problem of innerHTML:

1) Change this, and use computerChoice  to check computers play

```
 var computerChoice = compPlay();
```

2) In your `compPlay` function, change this:

```
return compOptions[randomChoice]; // you want the play, not the random number
```

Working version:

http://codepen.io/juvian/pen/pLqxD